# How to make template or theme for blogger blog?

Tags: web, themes, blogs, blogger

I have knowledge of HTML5, CSS, PHP, SQL, JS, JQUERY. But still I don't know how to make a blogger template, can anyone suggest me any resource of something that will help me in developing a blogger template?

Answer (score 3):

There is no official manual AFAIK. What I did is, switch to the standard blogger template (it's called "simple") and use the Backup/Restore function in Blogger. This will let you download the simple template as an XML file. As that template is quite basic, it's easy to study its structure and modify it accordingly. Basically, a Blogger template is made up of sections and widgets. A section is a container for widgets, and a widget is a specific content area in your Blog (such as the header, archive or the blog posts themselves).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one.

He has divided the tutorial into various parts:
https://web.archive.org/web/20111203194818/https://thesimplexdesign.com/2011/07/how-to-make-blogger-template-body-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Blogger Template also makes use of special Layout Tags.

Here is the comprehensive list:

http://blogger2ools.mystady.com/